# Jenkins-Docker plugin Configuration

Tags: jenkins-docker

I am trying to configure Docker-plugin in jenkins, need few details.

How to find URL ?
I verified with localhost:8080, Test connection failed with connection refused.
I am not sure what i am missing in the configuration.

Any please help with required details?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure docker is running on 8080: `netstat -nlp|grep 2375`
Which plugin are you using? Try [docker_commons_plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Commons+Plugin). To specify the Docker Host URI use tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 (if it's localhost)